# Istio VirtualService - broken URLs

Tags: url, kubernetes-ingress, istio

Help!

I am using Istio to setup a service mesh in Kubernetes. The Virtual Service definition routes the traffic to the desired service:

```
(...)
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /drill/
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: drill-service.drill.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8047
```

However, when calling the entrypoint

```
https://<HOST>:<NODEPORT_INGRESS_GW>/drill
```

I do see the HTML page, but the URLs are broken and CSS sheets are not loaded correctly. Reason is that the HTML source code points to the wrong targets:

```
li><a href="/storage">Storage</a></li>
```

instead of

```
li><a href="/drill/storage">Storage</a></li>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 2):

When you use [rewrite](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#HTTPRewrite) you need to add path in virtual service for your dependencies like css and js.

The whole process with rewrite and how it should be configured was well explained by @Rinor [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54023560/11977760).

---

This [Istio in practise](https://rinormaloku.com/istio-practice-routing-virtualservices/) tutorial also explains it well.

> Let’s break down the requests that should be routed to Frontend:
>
> **Exact path** / should be routed to Frontend to get the Index.html
>
> **Prefix path** /static/* should be routed to Frontend to get any static files needed by the frontend, like **Cascading Style Sheets** and **JavaScript files**.
>
> **Paths matching the regex ^.*.(ico|png|jpg)$** should be routed to Frontend as it is an image, that the page needs to show.

```
http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /
    - uri:
        exact: /callback
    - uri:
        prefix: /static
    - uri:
        regex: '^.*\.(ico|png|jpg)$'
    route:
    - destination:
        host: frontend             
        port:
          number: 80
```

---

Additionally you can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61927961/11977760).

---

**EDIT**

### Why your example does not work

With your current virtual service your requests will be as follows:

```
http://www.page.com/drill/

Rewritten: http://www.page.com/


http://www.page.com/drill/storage

Rewritten: http://www.page.com/storage
```

So now you would have to either change virtual service configuration, for example for paths without rewrite or change your app dependencies location, so istio could actually see `/drill/storage` path with your current virtual service, for now it see `/storage` path , and there is nothing here as the real path is `/drill/storage`.

```
http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
    - uri:
        prefix: /drill/storage/
    - uri:
        prefix: /...
```

### What I would suggest

If you have your domain configured as a virtual service host you might try with this virtual service:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: istio-vs
spec:
  hosts:
  - "drill.domain.com"
  gateways:
  - gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
    rewrite:
      uri: /drill/
    route:
    - destination:
        host: drill-service.drill.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8047
```

With this virtual service your requests will be as follows:

```
http://www.page.com/

Rewritten: http://www.page.com/drill/


http://www.page.com/storage

Rewritten: http://www.page.com/drill/storage
```

Comment: Hi Jakub, thanks for your answer, but this does not work (or I do not understand). I do see the examples on your references, but I have to extend the URL (adding drill) and not shorten as in the examples. After adding another URI the URLs are broken. Do I have to add rewrite-URI?

Comment: Hi @MBR I have edited my answer to explain to you why the current configuration does not work and what you might try to fix that.

Comment: Hi Jakub, thanks for your answer. I do want the configuration other way around. Incoming requests http://www.page.com/drill should be routed to http://drill-service.drill.svc.cluster.local/ 
It seems to be very simple, but I do not find any reference of how to do this. 

Regards Matthias

Comment: @MBR Even if you use only `- match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /` it's gonna be routed to drill-service anyway, you specified that as your virtual service host. The point is with your current configurations you'r urls are bad configured and it won't work.